# How to line-break 2 anchors

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I was trying to line-break my 2 anchors that i did using the `<a>` tag. They are inside a flip box.

Basically right now I have my 2 anchors `inline` but the problem is that I'm using flexbox on the container and I'm not really sure how I could break the 2nd anchor so it would be below my 1st anchor.

My HTML code : [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/slykikz/pen/QWpMXxL)

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;  justify-content: center;" class="flip-box-back">
  <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
  <a href="#" download>download</a>
  <hr>
  <div class="break">
    <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
    <a href="#">view</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I alreay tried the `<br>` and `<hr>` on HTML but without success.

Example :
[image: Here are my buttons that are side by side]

Thank you in advance, would be very grateful

Comment: please add a minimal reproduciable code snippet (**Ctrl+M**) that shows the issue. Within a `flexbox` the DOM structure is important. As such we cant help you without your providing necessary debugging details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i just edited the post and added a codepen ( don't look at the css inside the HTML ahaha i will change it)

Comment: PS: I edited your questions and removed all mentioning of `button` which refers to `<button>`. What you using are `anchors`. The wrong naming might have caused confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have to wrap each link and including the icon inside an element such as a div. Otherwise your icon and div will be placed all below each other and not just the 2 "buttons".

Then you can place each wrapped element by adding `flex-direction: column;`

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;  align-items: center;  justify-content: center;" class="flip-box-back">
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
    <a href="#" download>download</a>
  </div>
  <div class="break">
    <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
    <a href="#">view</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really need to thank you for the time you spendt with my question. Very grateful but i just have one last question about my HTML, am i doing it right ? or should i do it in another way in order to have the same result ?

Comment: always depends on the rest of your project. Your code would pass a markup validation: https://validator.w3.org/ - Often you have many different solutions. Then it comes down to your programming/skills and knowledge. Unless you are paid for efficiency, you could work with whatever solves an issue. There might be other reasons to work more efficient, but then it comes down to many different factors which would be to broad to explain in a short comment.

Comment: of course, i perfectly understand that, that's the reason why i created the post, because i saw many solutions but i wanted to be sure to have something that works and to clarify some things on such a particular subject.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `flex-flow: column;` to your div which wraps your buttons

```css
div {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 }
```

```html
<div>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Normally a flexbox is `no-wrap` so you need to add a property to let it break if there is no space left for 2 elements (also you can define the horizontal alignment to centered with `justify-content`) :

```css
.flexbox{
 display: flex;
}
.flexbox2{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}
.flexbox3{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

button{
  width: 60vw;
}
```

```html
Default:
<div class="flexbox">
 <button>Button1</button>
 <button>Button2</button>
</div>


With (auto) wrap:

<div class="flexbox2">
 <button>Button1</button>
 <button>Button2</button>
</div>

With forced wrap (column view):

<div class="flexbox3">
 <button>Button1</button>
 <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```